# Как перебрать массивы массивов через foreach

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь перебрать массивы массивов через `foreach`: Ошибка

```
int[][] anArray = {new int[] {123,432}, new int[] {543,542}};
foreach (int i in anArray) //ошибка
    foreach (int j in anArray[i])
        Console.WriteLine(anArray[i][j]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Но при переборе через `for` все хорошо

```
int[][] anArray = {new int[] {123,432}, new int[] {543,542}};
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < anArray[i].Length; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(anArray[i][j]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

В чем дело?

Comment: Потому что массив массивов, внезапно, это массив массивов, а не интов

Comment: какая ошибка-то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замени `int` на `var` в `foreach`.

У тебя же массив массивов => там `int[]`

Comment: И только? Этого не достаточно

Answer (score 5):

Правильно:

```
foreach (int[] arr in anArray)
    foreach (int x in arr)
        Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Цикл `foreach` используется для итерации по коллекции (или последовательности) и на каждом шаге он выдает следующий элемент конкретной коллекции (последовательности).
Цикл `for` же более универсален, на каждой итерации он просто меняет некую переменную (или несколько переменных, или ничего не меняет) по некоторому правилу, а также проверяет некие граничные условия (или ничего не проверяет), у вас, в частности, меняются в циклах `for` переменные `i`, `j`, которые вы используете в качестве индекса массива.

У вас массив массивов, поэтому внешний `foreach` возвращает поочередно все "внутренние" массивы из массива "внешнего".

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один метод, возможно, вам подойдёт:

```
foreach (int v in anArray.SelectMany(x => x))
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] anArray = {new int[] {123,432}, new int[] {543,542}};
foreach (int[] i in anArray) { // anArray содержит 2мерный массив, значит i должен быть массивом, а не элементом.
    foreach (int j in i) {
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
}
```