# Перечислить enum циклом for

Tags: c#, foreach, for

Как сделать так же только через цикл for

```
public class CardSetHelper
{
    public Deck Full()
    {
        var cardSet = new Stack<Card>();
        foreach (Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (CardName cardName in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardName)))
            {
                cardSet.Push(new Card { Suit = suit, Name = cardName });
            }
        }
        return new Deck { Cards = cardSet };
    }
}
```

Comment: А приведённый вами код вообще рабочий?

Comment: Любой цикл foreach можно переписать через for i. А в чём у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Думаю... это похоже на карточную игру, где раздаются 4 масти и набор от 6 до 10,К Д А.

Comment: @nick_n_a сложность возникла в том что не знаю что указывать вместо точек,пробовал разные варианты ,но не выходит  for(int i=0;i<...;i++)

Comment: Ну так вместо  ... пишите `(то_что_в_foreach).Length` или Count. `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)).Length`

Comment: @nick_n_a пробовал там где i< указывать последний элемент enum ,но это не работает ,возможно не правильно указывал

Comment: @nick_n_a сейчас попробую

Comment: @nick_n_a да,это сработало ,спасибо

Comment: Только, это тот случай когда `foreach` запись куда компактнее. Не вижу смысла тут `for i` лепить

Comment: @nick_n_a знаю ,но какие ставят условия ,те и приходится выполнять

Comment: А может вы объясните, зачем вам for? Узнаю [свой код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795638/213987) в вопросе, но не понимаю, зачем вам нужно переделывать. Вы опять спрашиваете "как мне это сделать", но вам ещё нужно научиться пояснять "для чего я хочу это сделать:" - может вам [не нужен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4900/213987) for для вашей задачи.

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730726/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так: [rextester](http://rextester.com/HAO28597), но это крайне не красиво.

```
public static void Foreach_2()
{
    Type t1 = typeof(Suit);
    Array a1 = t1.GetEnumValues();
    for(var i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        Type t2 = typeof(CardName);
        Array a2 = t2.GetEnumValues();
        for(var j = 0; j < a2.Length; j++)
        {
            Suit v1 = (Suit)a1.GetValue(i);
            CardName v2 = (CardName)a2.GetValue(j);
            Console.WriteLine(v1+", "+v2);
        }
    }
}
```